# Network Request Failed on the Real mobile devices ,React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, ssl

The React Native App(Android) does not work on the any devices(mobile device and emulator). I always see network request errors. So I added the network_security_config.xml file to the xml holder, but it still doesn't work. Backend url is 'https://prvmsg.com' I've been grappling with this problem for a week.Please help me.

---network-security-config.xml---

```
enter code here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <!-- Localhost config is NEEDED from react-native for the bundling to work  -->
        <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
            <domain includeSubdomains="true">127.0.0.1</domain>
            <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.0.1</domain>
            <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
        </domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">newbiefans.com</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/ca"/>
            <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: What exatly does not work? Please add error output, debugging info etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTTP then you have to use

Add use usesCleartextTraffic=”true” in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: prvmsg.com is https.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).